# Silver-haired humanoid?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

In [episode 16](https://www.crunchyroll.com/that-time-i-got-reincarnated-as-a-slime/episode-16-demon-lord-milim-attacks-780733), timecode 9:10, of *That Time I Got Reincarnated as a Slime*, Milim refers to Rimuru's human form as being a "Silver-haired humanoid". Here is Rimuru (right) and Milim:

[image]

Did they just have a bad translation, or does "silver" refer to some broader range of hues in Japanese? Or maybe Milim has some sort of weird color blindness, or sees only in black and white? I'm pretty sure most watchers have assumed Rimuru's hair color is blue, the same color as his slime form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in the original web novel Rimuru's slime form is silver and the human form is described as having silver hair. But in the light novel and manga adaptations they changed it to blue. The anime's art and story are more closely based on the manga than the webnovel, so I'd guess that's why he appears as having blue hair in the anime too.

In the scene you're referring to, Milim does actually call him silver-haired and it's not a bad translation. Maybe blue just looks better on screen, I don't know why they do this. Although, there are some other anime too where the hair color looks different from what it's supposed to be, I don't pay it much heed.

Comment: Oh, so Milim could be making a sort of Easter-egg callback to the web novel? With Rimuru out of the loop, and having to ask her, "Is this the form you are referring to?"

Comment: Actually, if you see the manga, Milim asks Rimuru about the silver-haired human she saw in Gelmud's crystal ball because she is as of yet uncertain if that was Rimuru himself. To which, Rimuru transforms, and says "Might this be the form you're referring to?", thus clearing Milim of any doubt that it really was him.